# Android CalendarView show selected Date after coming back to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, calendarview

I'm using a CalendarView on my activity, that shows some events on selected date. If an event is clicked, a new activity is started and showing some details of the event. Everything works fine. But if I go back to previous activity, 'today' is selected (it's my default). Is it possible to go back to the date of the event I selected?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can save it in the variable when shifting to activity and set it back when you load the activity back.

Comment: I worked on it for days, but couldn't fix it... Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: I tried the following way:
- using startActivityForResult to start the event activity
- override onBackPressed in event activity and set selected date to the intent
- override onActivityResult in calendar fragment and the selected Date as an argument (using getArguments().putLong..)
I debugged everything and the arguement in fragment is set, but in the following onCreate of the fragment, the argument is null. Is this the wrong way? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the one thing when you select date at that time store that date into static variable or anywhere and when you came back to that activity set that day,month and year to that date picker dialog that way you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use a static variable, the date is always set, isn't it? I just want to set selected date, after coming back to calendar activity from event activity - not if activity is calendar is called again from menu

Comment: You can reset it to default or any value you want when being called from menu .

Comment: I used static variable in fragment and it works. Tanks for your help!